# assign indices in order of appearance

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({"user_hash": ["b","a","c", "a"]})
> df
  user_hash
0         b
1         a
2         c
3         a
```

where `user_hash` represents long hash values, so for clarity I'd like to add a column that just enumerates the elements in order of appearance. In the example my desired result would be:

```
> df2
  user_hash user_id
0         b       0
1         a       1
2         c       2
3         a       1
```

This question comes very close: [Q: [Pandas] How to efficiently assign unique ID to individuals with multiple entries based on name in very large df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685254/q-pandas-how-to-efficiently-assign-unique-id-to-individuals-with-multiple-ent#45685337) but since it relies on `groupby` the order of ids is the natural order of the sorted entries whereas I want the ids to be in order of appearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pd.factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
labels, _ = pd.factorize(df['user_hash'])
result = df.assign(user_id=labels)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  user_hash  user_id
0         b        0
1         a        1
2         c        2
3         a        1
```

Or as an alternative use [ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
result = df.assign(user_id=df.groupby('user_hash', sort=False).ngroup())
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  user_hash  user_id
0         b        0
1         a        1
2         c        2
3         a        1
```

Comment: `df.assign(user_id=df['user_hash'].factorize()[0])` also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single instruction:

```
df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.user_hash.unique(), columns=['user_hash'])
    .reset_index(), how='left')
```

The result is:

```
  user_hash  index
0         b      0
1         a      1
2         c      2
3         a      1
```

If you want, change the second column name (*index*) to any other of your choice.