# How to add unique alphanumeric id for pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I need a solution where i can generate unique alphanumeric id column for my dataframe. I need that the ids remain same even if I run the script later in future.

```
    Name
    Sam
    Pray
    Brad
```

I can generate the ids based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685254/q-pandas-how-to-efficiently-assign-unique-id-to-individuals-with-multiple-ent) but I need 5 digit aplhanumeric values which will always remain same.

This is desired output:

```
    Name         ID
    Sam          X25TR
    Peter        WE558
    Pepe         TR589
```

Answer (score -1):

This function generate random alphanumeric string with given length:

```
import math
import secrets


def random_alphanum(length: int) -> str:
        text = secrets.token_hex(nbytes=math.ceil(length / 2))
        isEven = length % 2 == 0
        return text if isEven else text[1:]
```

---

```
df['ID'] == random_alphanum(5)
```

---

Apply to whole rows:

```
df2['ID'] = df2.apply(lambda x: random_alphanum(5), axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

Comment: OP said he wanted a unique number that is always the same, not a random number, so I guess he's talking about a hash.

Comment: Do you test it?

Comment: @jezrael - yas, edited - there is need to add .apply with reseult_type="expand" - to have unique record per row.

Comment: @PiotrŻak Are you sure? OP dont need unique value per row.

Comment: could U look at output? - there were 3 different values per each name.

Comment: I think OP need unique values per `Name`, not per rows.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to generate a hash of the name, by whatever hashing algorithm, and keep the first five characters of the hash. But you should keep in mind that with such as short hash this is likely to cause collisions (same output for multiple different inputs) if you have enough data.

Something along these lines:

```
import hashlib

def get_id(name: str) -> str:
    hash = hashlib.md5(name.encode())
    return hash.hexdigest()[:5]
```

Now for a given input string, `get_id` returns an alphanumeric 5-character string which is always the same for the same input.

Comment: Side note: if the output may be case-sensitive you get less collisions if you take the first 8 characters of the md5 hash and convert them from hex (base 16 [0-9a-f]) to base 62 [0-9a-zA-Z], where ``ffffffff`` (16) equals ``4GFfc3`` (62)

Comment: Sorry, ``4GFfc3`` is obviously 6 characters. So make that 7 md5 characters: ``fffffff`` (16) = ``iakk7`` (62)

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt

```
import secrets

 ids = []
 while len(ids) < df.shape[0]:
     temp = secrets.token_hex(5)[:5]
     if temp not in ids:
         ids.append(temp)
         

df.merge(pd.DataFrame(ids).reset_index(), left_on = df.groupby(['Name']).ngroup(), right_on =  'index')
```